# What is the difference between mobile smartphone vs xHTML/WML vs cHTML in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: mobile, seo, google-search-console

Fetch as Google has 3 mobile options for Googlebot type, mobile smartphone vs xHTML/WML vs cHTML. What the difference and if I submit for index as one type, does it automatically getting submitted for other types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile smartphone is the most common option.  The other two are for features phones (such as flip phones with web browsers) and older-generation web-enabled phones, like the ones that were popular in in Japan before the smartphone revolution.